# On La Vagabonde what Citizen Science is Possible?

Tags: oceanography, science-fair-project

The Catamaran [La Vagabonde](https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:4997037/mmsi:227497060/imo:0/vessel:LA_VAGABONDE) is a high tech vessel that's designed to be as carbon neutral as possible.

Subject to the constraints of space, time and safety, what citizen science projects would be possible on this vessel?

Comment: Are sure ? Isn't it just a serial yacht of which many (many, many, many) sail out there (manufacturer Outremer) ? Maybe with a few modifications ? And is a 15-20 ton vessel of resin, fibre, 2 diesel engines, anti-fouling paint (renewed every 2-3 years), aluminium/stell standing rigg, plastic running gear, plastic sails (wearing parts as well) really carbon neutral ? That can be debated ... anyway, sailing the open ocean is a nice hobby for those who can afford it, i can tell ;-)

Comment: Hope i am talking about the same. Looking at their website https://sailing-lavagabonde.com/ i think they are just a lucky couple sailing the ocean, and i am not jealous at all because i was lucky too until i ran out of money. I doubt they have a laboratory on board, but they can help collect data like sea/air temperature, salinity, currents, wind etc. pp. But every ship can do that, and the countries weather services have ocean data collection devices well distributed, plus satellite data, etc. A citizen can't compete with that, i am sorry.

Comment: If this is right and the same, they got the boat because of their influencer status. Now i am getting a little jealous :-) But it may be that science is not the driving force here ...
https://www.bravotv.com/below-deck/blogs/instagram-fame-pays-sailing-couple-on-permanent-vacation-wins-million-dollar-yacht

Comment: Maybe their citizen science was to make a new human lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, trying an answer. I don't know if citizen science is actually done. Possible would be sample collection, physical data (water temperature, air temperature), weather conditions, sigthings of rubbish, animals or unusual phenomena. Actually, before the space age ships collected and exchanged weather data to produce on ship weather charts for example. Afaik, this is not practical any more, merchant ships anyway and increasingly recreational vessels (if the owner can afford) have satellite data and internet on board.

Data collection in itself is no problem, but the calibration to make them comparable and combinable is. In simple words, one can't just buy a thermometre and bind it to the mast, they'd differ by a lot. Recreative vessels have their routes on the oceans. In Atlantic terms, now (November) they set out in hundreds and thousands into the Caribbean, in spring some them return (the northern route is more strenuous ;-)). There is not that much to be had science wise because they all measure similar things (in between the sunbathing on their catamarans).

And, there actually is concern that too much citizen science could leave a negative carbon footprint.

Something to read: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4159111/